# How to avoid servlet responding with new html page?

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets

Following are my get() and post() method of my servlet. I am very new to servlet. When I call from my client, this servlet create a new page and overwrite all my html elements in my client. What I want to do is I just stay remain in my html page and let servlet do his job alone.

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, 
               HttpServletResponse response)
              throws ServletException, java.io.IOException {
      // Check that we have a file upload request
      isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);

      DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
      // maximum size that will be stored in memory
      factory.setSizeThreshold(maxMemSize);
      // Location to save data that is larger than maxMemSize.
      factory.setRepository(new File("c:\\temp"));

      // Create a new file upload handler
      ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
      // maximum file size to be uploaded.
      upload.setSizeMax( maxFileSize );

      try{ 
      // Parse the request to get file items.
      List fileItems = upload.parseRequest(request);

      // Process the uploaded file items
      Iterator i = fileItems.iterator();

      while ( i.hasNext () ) 
      {
         FileItem fi = (FileItem)i.next();
         if ( !fi.isFormField () )  
         {
            // Get the uploaded file parameters
            String fieldName = fi.getFieldName();
            String fileName = fi.getName();
            String contentType = fi.getContentType();
            boolean isInMemory = fi.isInMemory();
            long sizeInBytes = fi.getSize();
            // Write the file
            if( fileName.lastIndexOf("\\") >= 0 ){
               file = new File( filePath + 
               fileName.substring( fileName.lastIndexOf("\\"))) ;
            }else{
               file = new File( filePath + 
               fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf("\\")+1)) ;
            }
            fi.write( file ) ;

         }
      }

   }catch(Exception ex) {
       System.out.println(ex);
   }
   }
   public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, 
                       HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, java.io.IOException {

        throw new ServletException("GET method used with " +
                getClass( ).getName( )+": POST method required.");
   }
```

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ changed title and thanks for your answer.

Comment: My pleasure to help you :) Mark it as answer, If you found it helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What I want to do is I just stay remain in my html page and let servlet do his job alone.

This is the perfect candidate for using [Asynchronous call](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) AKA Ajax.

Learn AJAX.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

[How to use Servlets and Ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112686/how-to-use-servlets-and-ajax)

Answer (score 0):

If you want servlet should do process and it should show html page then you can use `RequestDispatcher` at the end of your try block in servlet. So when click on any action from your html page it will o to servlet and do proper action their and again it will redirect to html.

```
RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("index.html");
            rd.include(request, response);
```